# What's the best approach to support iPad and iPhone in my App?

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, ip

I'm working on App that should support both: iPhone-portrait, iPad-landscape, so there are different design for iPhone, iPad, **But** the functionality is the same.

My question is: what's the best way to support the iPad without repeating the controllers?

I thought to make another storyboard for the iPad, but what about the controllers? how can i use the same controllers of the iPhone although there is different in design?

anyone faced the same problem?

thanks,

Comment: use Auto Layout if you are use landscape and portrait screen. otherwise you can user autorsizingmask.

Comment: sizeClasses is your friend, you can do everything with only one storyboard

Comment: U also can use seprated storyboard for iphone and ipad if want cleaner storyboard

Comment: @ChandraVaghasiya actually it's to late to edit my iPhone design to make as Auto Layout.

Comment: @Tj3n yeah that's what i thought about, but my problem is in repeat the controllers!! 
how can i use the same controllers even if i'm in separate storyboard?

Comment: @Drizztneko size class can be suitable if the design no different mush. but in my case the design between iPhone and iPad different a lot.

Comment: it doesnt matter, separate storyboard but u still can use the viewcontroller name for both storyboard viewcontroller, in iphone storyboard u got VC1 then in ipad storyboard u also can have VC1, if need some code to execute depends on iphone and ipad then just put some check before doing it

Comment: there is no problem with that, you can create specific styles for each device :) but it's true that it could be a little confusing. I think that you will have no problem using the same VC in different SB. the only think that you have to take account is to use the same iboulets

Comment: @Tj3n thanks so mush, but if my controller have an oultet for button for example but in iPad i don't have this button. how to solve this problem?

Comment: @Drizztneko  thanks alot. please can u check my previous comment?

Comment: then just don't put it inside the ipad storyboard, it shouldnt cause anything wrong, if it cause crash then consider do a check to see if its iphone and ipad and configure based on that

Comment: @Tj3n hmmm, i try it and there is an exception in the outlet that i've took it from iPhone storyboard. so how to check that in iPad?

Comment: @Rawan thats weird, it shouldnt be any error if u din add the button to the ipad storyboard, if it needs then also can create invisible button also fine, for the check then there're a lot of question already answer it, please search google

Answer (score 0):

Consider using **Coordinators**, see [this post](http://khanlou.com/2015/10/coordinators-redux/) by Soroush Khanlou.